# Ternary operator works wrong in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, conditional-operator

I have a problem when rendering components based on conditional in reactJS. 
My expectation is the paragraph will be shown **all of the content** if it is in pdf view. Meanwhile, it will be displayed **a part of the content with the "Show more" button** if it is on the edit page. 
Both pages use ComponentA to render the paragraph. 
I have an isPdf prop which was passed from the parent to check pdf file:

```
const ComponentA = ({isPdf}) => {...}
```

Render component:

```
{!isPdf ? <RsReadMore width={1000}>{actualContent}</RsReadMore> : <RsFullContent>{actualContent}</RsFullContent>}
```

When I print isPdf on the console to test. It displays true on pdf page and false on edit page (Correct). 
However, it still shows **a part of the content with the "Show more" button** on both two pages. 
Which are some reasons that make this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Could you post code for both `RsReadMore` and `RsFullContent`?

Comment: Can you try console.log(typeof isPdf) ? Please verify the type of isPdf so you are sure it is boolean - it could be read as string

Comment: @user20386762 just 2 style components, I think it's not a point

Comment: @BorislavStefanov thank you, but it's boolean

Comment: Please post them, ternary operator works correctly in React. `condition ? true : false`. Is there any reason you are inverting the condition though?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen Is it possible to create short Sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/